# How do I connect to sqlplus in bash script without editing the tnsnames.ora file?

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to create a bash script to run an SQL query. The issue that I have is that the connection strings that I am using below is only giving me errors.

Example connection attempts with errors:

`sqlplus -s username/password@hostname:Port:SID` --> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

`sqlplus -s username/password@hostname:Port/SID` --->  ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Comment: show your working tnsname

Comment: I can't seem to find the tnsname.ora file.

Comment: Is there a way that I can create it?

Comment: You can use either `username/password@[//][host][:port][/service_name]` or `username/password@[//][host][:port][:SID]`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I tried what you suggested however I get ORA-1245: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist. I know the credentials I am putting in the string is correct because I use the same ones with SQL Developer. Do you have any idea where I should go from here?

Comment: What did you discover when you googled 'ora-1245'?  (actually, that's ora-12545', you mis-typed the error code).  This error means that when oracle TNS passed the request to the OS network stack, that your specified 'hostname' could not be resolved to an actual host (server name/ip address).

Comment: Do you have an entry like `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(tnsnames, ezconnect)` in your sqlnet.ora? (Do you have a sqlnet.ora? `tnsping \ ` should print the path it's using.)

Answer (score 0):

Example on my (local) XE database. Let's just check what `TNSNAMES.ORA` says (I obfuscated host name) so that you'd see what I used while connecting to the database. If you don't have `TNSNAMES.ORA`, then you'll have to find that info *somehow* (possibly by asking your DBA).

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_host)(PORT = 1521)) 
(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
```

OK, let's try it now:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@my_host:1521/xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Svi 4 21:52:46 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Using localhost's IP address (as I said, XE runs on my laptop):

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@127.0.0.1:1521/xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Svi 4 21:53:07 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Using localhost itself:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost:1521/xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Svi 4 21:56:17 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: What does TCP stand for? When I looked it up all it said it was the default port number but the port number is already being used.